# Как избавиться от мелькания белого фона при скролле страницы

Tags: css

Всем привет.Суть вопроса такая-на странице есть несколько фоновых изображений.Первое расположенное в header отображается нормально, а вот те, которые идут ниже..при скролле они появляются не сразу, а с миллисекундной задержкой, как будто подгружаются.Кто знает в чем причина и как этого избежать.Где -то встречал подобное обсуждение но не смог найти..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может вы сами ответили на свой вопрос "подгружаются" ,  так нужно пример кода

Comment: страница слишком большая, чтобы выкладывать пример.мне кажется в вопросе изложена суть и все понятно.Пусть даже это связано с загрузкой изображений, но как от этого избавиться?Делать предзагрузку изображений или можно просто какими-то методами css это исправить?

Comment: оптимизируйте изображение , встройте их в html c помощью "data:URL"

Comment: понял.спасибо за совет и ответ.думаю это поможет.